# Python: array of points to JSON

Tags: python, dlib

I am new to Python and I am trying since this morning to convert an object (which I believe it's an array of points) to JSON.

```
print "myobject type is: %s" % type(myobject)
print "myobject[0] is %s" % myobject[0]
myobjectJson = json.dumps(myobject)
```

result

```
 myobject type is: class 'dlib.dlib.points'

 myobject[0] is (190, 254)

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./face_landmark_detection.py", line 103, in <module>
    myobjectJson = json.dumps(myobject)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <dlib.dlib.points object at 0x1086db650> is not JSON serializable
```

so, as far as I can see this object is not JSON serializable.

I have tried to use:

```
myobjectJson = json.dumps(myobject, default=list)
myobjectJson = json.dumps(myobject, default=tuple)
myobjectJson = json.dumps(myobject, default=dict)
myobjectJson = json.dumps(myobject, default=__dict__)
myobjectJson = json.dumps(myobject, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

But I keep getting the same error...
what can I do?

Thank you

**update**

```
dir myobject is: ['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instance_size__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__safe_for_unpickling__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'append', 'clear', 'extend', 'resize']
dir myobject[0] is: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instance_size__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__safe_for_unpickling__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'x', 'y']
```

Comment: What sort of structure were you hoping to end up with? You have something resembling a list of tuples at the moment; it has no keys.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to print this list of tuples, as it is, to a JSON string. or maybe to another array which I can convert to JSON. Anything is fine I just need to print this output in a correct JSON format

Comment: JSON supports lists of lists (or arrays of arrays might be the correct term). I guess that's the closest to what you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `myobject` is a list of tuples:

```
import json
myobjectJson = json.dumps([list(x) for x in myobject])
```

Not a list of tuples, eh? Try:

```
myobjectJson = json.dumps([list[p.x, p.y] for p in myobject])
```

or

```
myobjectJson = json.dumps([(p.x, p.y) for p in myobject])
```

In this case, you feed the list to `json.dumps()` and don't need to modify the data so the result should be the same whether you make a list of tuples or a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks, I get this error: TypeError: 'point' object is not iterable. Unbelievable.... why a simple task is this complicated in Python?

Comment: Ok, then it's not a regular list of tuples. What *are* `myobject` and `point`? Check `dir(myobject[0])` and post the output. `point` might have it's own `.values()` or `to_string()` class methods.

Comment: I have updated the question with the 2 outputs. I cannot see .values or to_string in none of them.

Comment: Cool. Updated my answer

Comment: Many thanks I was working on something like that! :-)

Comment: You're welcome :) You don't have to use `list()` btw. I think `json.dumps()` converts anything with an index into an array so `(p.x, p.y) ...` (implicitly making it a tuple) is shorter and would work as well